# Does python interpreter keep py or pyc file of currently running script in a temporary folder?

Tags: python

After 3 intensive hour, I was testing my script on terminal. However, my editor messed up and it overwrote my script when it was being still executed on terminal. Well, I didn't terminate running script, so I was wondering that does python interpreter keep the currently running file in a temporary folder or somewhere else so that I can recover my script?

Comment: Yep... Sorry to say, this is what source control is for. It's a painful lesson and one we've all learnt at some point or other.

Comment: If the file is still open in your editor, consider undo (Ctrl+Z). It may be able to roll back a lot of history.

Comment: I tried ctrl+z but it was too late (because my editor is shitty editor.) @Basic you are right I need to use source control. However, I use source control for large scale project. This project was pet project of mine. Anyway, I still have rest of the code, I will reimplement parts that are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to cache your .pyc files. How that's done has changed over time (see [PEP 3147 -- PYC Repository Directories](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/). Top level scripts are not cached but imported ones are. So, you may not have one.

.pyc files are compiled byte codes so its not just a question of renaming it .py and you can't figure them out just by looking at them. There are decompilers out there like the one refenced here:
[Decompiling .pyc files](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/decompiling-pyc-files).

Personally, I create mercurial repos for my scripts and check them in frequently.... because I've made a similar mistake a time or two. git, svn, and etc... are other popular tools for maintaining repos.

Depending on your operating system and editor, you may have a copy in Trash or even saved by the editor. You may also be able to "roll back" the file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Linux, you may still be able to find a handle to open files in the /proc/ directory if the process is still running. This handle will keep the file from being deleted. Details see: https://superuser.com/questions/283102/how-to-recover-deleted-file-if-it-is-still-opened-by-some-process

Comment: Thank you, I am on Linux and the process was still running however I couldn't recover the file and unfortunately the program threw exception and  stopped executing. So now officially, there is no way to recover the file :)